# FacesMessage is not displayed when being set in an action method with a redirect outcome

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Why the code from the first block works and the other one doesn't? It's all about displaying JSF messages

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        i18nExceptionHandler.handleException(e);
    }
}
```

The code above works well - it displays the message.

```
public String login() {
    try {
       //login actions
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
      //this doesn't work
        i18nExceptionHandler.handleException(e);
    }
    return "/pages/loggedin?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

This code doesn't work - it doesn't display any message and I'm given following error:

```
WARNING: There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.
```

Why it works like that? Shall I use validator or something else on the login method (and the rest as well)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message from the second code block wasn't displayed, because method hasn't got void signature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include h:messages tag in your jsf page. for example,

```
<h:messages id="messagesID" globalOnly="true" layout="table" />
```

If you don't have this in your JSF page, the warning message will arise.

Comment: I've got h:message tag - I must have it, since first code block works (and handleException(throwable) method adds faces message)